# If $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f'(x) = l \in \Bbb R$. Does it mean $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f'(c) = l$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f'(x) = l \in \Bbb
 R$.

1) Does it mean that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f'(c) = l$?

2) Is it possible that $f'(c)$ does not exist?

3) What is the difference whether $f$ is continuous or not?

4) If $f$ is continuous, how to prove the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f'(x) = l \in \Bbb
 R$  then $f$ is differentiable at $c$ **provided that $f$ is continuous at $c$**. Then by the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Formal_statement), there is $t_x$ between $x$ and $c$ such that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(t_x).$$
It follows that, as $x\to c$, we have $t_x\to c$ and $f'(t_x)\to l$.
Hence $f'(c)$ exists and it is equal to $l$.

Of course, if **$f$ is not continuous at $c$** or if **$f$ is not even defined at $c$**, then $f$ is not differentiable at $c$. Take for example 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 &  \text{if $x=0$}\\ x & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}.$$
Then $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=1$, but the $f$ is not differentiable at $0$:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x-1}{x}=-\infty.$$

Comment: Could you give more hints?

Comment: @Robert Z How do you get that $f'(t_x)\to l$ as $t_x \to c$ implies $f'(c) = l$ ? Wouldn't you require $f$ to be $C^1$ for that to happen?

Comment: @Deepakms NO. It follows from the assumption that $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f'(x) = l$.

Comment: @kenkenb Maybe you could show some effort and fill the gaps...

Comment: @ Robert Z ok. thanks for your effort anyway

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that $f'(c)$ does not even exist.  The existence of a limit of derivative does not even guarantee continuity of $f$ at $c$. For example consider a constant function with a jump discontinuity at $c$.
$$F(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x \neq 1 \\ 1 &  x=1\end{cases}$$ is not differentiable at 1 even though the limit of derivative exist when $x$ tends to 1.

Comment: In fact , it is not even mean that $f$ is defined at $c$